# Make a completed Ethernet cable snagless after it was crimped

Tags: ethernet, cable, connector

If I have an Ethernet cable with RJ-45 connectors crimped on both ends and having **no** snagless boot protection, what are my options for making the cable snagless after the fact?

Sure, if the RJ-45 connectors were not yet committed to the cable, then I could buy connector boot covers and put them on the cable and then crimp the connectors. But alas, my contractor has crimped 256 cables without providing snagless solution, so now I need to work around it.

Replacing the cables entirely is not an option, as these 256 cables run in the plenum between 20 different rooms.

Re-crimping all 256 cables is also not a great option as this is a horrible amount of less than pleasant work.

The only idea I have so far is to buy the boots, cut them longitudinally with a razor knife, put them around the cable and then glue the cut. But this is also a lot of manual work, although not as bad as recrimping all the connectors. Is there any other well-known solution to this problem?

Comment: *"Re-crimping all 256 cables is also not a great option as this is a horrible amount of less than pleasant work."*  but that is what the contractor is for, not you, right? _-_   *"These 256 cables run in the plenum between 20 different rooms."* But why have RJ45 connectors on your structured cabling in the first place, rather than patch-panels with RJ-45  on one end and RJ-45 wall-outlets on the other, which can easily last a decade.  And then short, flexible , easily replaced patch cables to whatever devices need to be connected?

Comment: why do you need snagless cables in a fixed install location?

Comment: That's a good point, why is the solid conductor plenum cable terminated with an RJ45 connector, instead of a patch panel? Those will be flimsy and problematic.

Comment: To respond to 3 comments above: cables are crimped with RJ-45 connectors because I invest into feed-through patch panels which allows me to never crimp the cable to a patch panel. This gives me configurability both on front and back sides of the patch panels and does not tie the rack to the building. Yes, it costs more, and I love paying more for a better, more configurable setup.

Comment: As to why protect the RJ-45 connector latches against snagging in a stationary setup... Exactly because I want to be able to disconnect at the back of the feed-through patch panel at will and not be afraid to damage the latch. Again, I am not looking to save money, I am looking to build a neat, slightly over-engineered and future-proof setup.

Comment: Yup, and that violates any standard. It's a violation of best practices, which makes your question off-topic. I am an electrician and IT guy and I've learned both jobs from trainee to certified. A patch panel always terminates a wall socket. If you want to overengineer the rack, use a good cabling idea. The newer patch panels click into place, providing a single small socket available for patching, and if needed, you can place them in any direction.

Comment: I am sure you will be kind and knowledgeable enough to expand a vague "any standard" statement into a specific list of standards and sections therein that are being violated... It is certainly a shocking news to me that feed-through patch panels that are being sold left and right at a premium price are now suddenly illegal.

Comment: @RegusPregus See ISO/IEC 11801-2 or ANSI/TIA-568-B1 for the relevant standards.

Comment: Just searched entire ANSI/TIA-568-B.1 and nowhere it says that I am not allowed to terminate Ethernet cables with male RJ-45 connectors and then plug them into the back side of a feed-through patch panel. Please, stop arguing on an irrelevant tangent, I have already solved the original problem myself, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody has provided any constructive advice aside from attacking irrelevant aspects of the problem, here is the answer that my colleague at work was able to provide: the type of product that solves exactly this problem is called snap-in RJ45 boot (sometimes called "snap on RJ45 boot").